# what will happen if one linked list reachs its last value

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm supposed to analyze a `mystery` method and hand simulate the call `mystery(x,y)` using the linked lists in this image:

[image: The linked list]

The first time it executes, `a = 6 t = 3 b = 3, a.next.next = 6`

The second time it executes, `t = /, a = 7, b = /, a.next.next = /`

The third time it executes, `a` already reaches its last value, in this case, does the iteration stop? Or does it keep going with the value `a = /`?

Can someone explain to me what will happen if it keeps going?

Here's the code with proper formatting:

```
def mystery(a,b):
    while b != None:
        t = a.next.next
        a.next.next = b
        a = b
        b = t
```

Comment: show us the code for the linked list implementation. This is a highly implementation-specific question which cannot be answered without the class definition of the linked list itself

Comment: ok, I just did...

Comment: The function you've edited into your post talks about how the linked list is used. It doesn't show the definition of `class LinkedList`. Further, `mystery` seems to swap two nodes in the linked list, which explains the observed behavior in your print statements

Comment: Did you see the picture I posted?

Comment: _"what will happen if one linked list reachs its last value?.."_ - the end of the world! >:)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the loop condition. The function will stop looping when `b` is `None`. It could also stop with an exception if `a` or `a.next` are `None` before `b` becomes `None`, since looking up `a.next.next` in that situation will not be valid (since `None` doesn't have a `next` attribute). That won't happen with the linked lists in your image.

Your description of how the different variables change as the loop happens appears incorrect. After the second iteration of the loop, `a` is going to be a reference to the `3` node and `b` will be a reference to the `8` node. I suggest walking through the code some more.

Here's a quick rundown of how the values change in the first two iterations of the loop:

1. When the function is called, `a` is bound to `x` (a reference to the `1` node) and `b` is bound to `y` (a reference to the `6` node).
2. The `while` statement will check that `b` is not None. It's not, so we go into the loop body.
3. `t` gets bound to `a.next.next`. That's the `3` node.
4. `a.next.next` gets rebound to `b`. This makes the `2` node have its arrow point to the `6` node instead of the `3` node.
5. `a` gets rebound to `b`, so `a` now points to the `6` node.
6. `b` is rebound to `t`, so it points to the `3` node.
7. We've reached the end of the loop, so we go back to the top and retest the loop condition.
8. `b` is still not `None`, so we keep looping.
9. `t` gets rebound to `a.next.next`, which is the `8` node.
10. `a.next.next` gets rebound to `b`, so the arrow from the `7` node starts pointing to the `3` node instead of the `8` node.
11. `a` gets rebound to `b`, so it points to the `3` node.
12. `b` gets rebound to `t`, so it points to the `8` node.
13. And we repeat again....

Comment: In your step 4, could you tell me why does a.nextnext is 2 node instead of 3 node, because in the step 3 you refer a.next.next to 3 node.

Comment: `a.next.next` is the arrow from the 2 to the 3 node. When you bind `t` to `a.next.next`, `t` then points to the same place (to the 3 node). When you rebind `a.next.next`, you make it point somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I understand most of it. one more question, can you explain why a points to the 3 node in your 11 step? I cant understand when b is bounded to the 3 node.

Comment: Whoops, I had a typo on steps 4 and 5. I've fixed it so `a` becomes `6`, then `b` becomes `3`. This should help the later steps make more sense.